# How to add data scraped into my list, I am unable to print "ranking_list" and have it not be empty

Tags: python, selenium, dropdown, screen-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://www.nbatopshot.com/listings/p2p/208ae30a-a4fe-42d4-9e51-e6fd1ad2a7a9+543a9cf6-4881-4e77-8a7e-ffcb740691db?serialNumber=107")

element = driver.find_element_by_id("moment-detailed-serialNumber")
drp=Select(element)

#drp.select_by_index(2)
all_options = drp.options

ranking_list = {}
for index, option in enumerate(all_options):
    if index == 0:
        continue
    else:
        if index >0:
            option.text.split(" - ")
            #print(option.text.split(" - "))
print(ranking_list)
```

How to add data scraped into my list? I am unable to print `"ranking_list"` and have it not be empty.

Comment: Of course, because you never added anything to `ranking_list`.  What did you expect to put in there?

Comment: also, you have it named ranking_list, and want to scrape into your "list",  but are defining it as a dictionary

Comment: I'm trying to add option.text.split(" - ") into ranking_list. I want to then use the data for analysis. I can do print(option.text.split(" - "), but, I'm not sure how to add it into a list.